# MinGW for Windows doesn't work when I try to link with LD

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit, mingw, ld, djgpp

I am developing a test OS right now in C... and I've been looking on http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/brans-kernel-development-tutorial to get started. I got MinGW for Windows 7 (64-bit). I set up a linker script which is in the tutorial and a batch file to automate the build with NASM, GCC, and LD. When it tries to link the .o files with LD, I get this message "ld: cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file". Why is this happening?

Also, the reason I have MinGW instead of DJGPP (which it says on the second page under Compilers) is because I could not find a download that worked on Windows 64-bit. I got a message saying that 16-bit applications are incompatible with my version of Windows.

If anyone could help with this... I would really appreciate that! :)

Comment: You might want to try running DJGPP in Win7's XP Mode: http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/2/C/72C7BAB7-2F32-4530-878A-292C20E1845A/WindowsXPMode_en-us.exe and http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/5/0554AE99-785F-45CB-B1F2-0E3ED1E6117D/Windows6.1-KB958559-x64-RefreshPkg.msu

Comment: I have Home Premium... I'm not sure if this works... I'll try downloading the update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about this. But I think this is because a compiler for the MinGW target takes some extra steps needed for producing a Windows executable. So it might be easier to build a generic elf cross compiler (targeting x86_64-unknown-elf), at least much easier than [building a cross compiler targeting DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/howto/djgpp/linux-x-djgpp.html).